# Xml doc - <see> tag on parameter

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

Is it possible to use the `<see cref=""/>` tag to reference a parameter?
What I mean is something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Method with parameter <see cref="foo"/>.
/// </summary>
public static void Foo(int foo)
{

}
```

Resharper tells me that this is correct. But if I build the project, the build process tells me that it is not correct and that `foo` can't be resolved. I've also tried to sand castle tool which also gives me a warning that `foo` can't be resolved.

So is there any possibility to reference a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference a parameter you need to use [`<paramref>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb7x2fhw.aspx):

```
/// <summary>
/// Method with parameter <paramref name="foo"/>.
/// </summary>
```